# AMD64 or x86 64-bit package for ZULU OpenJRE 7 on Windows OS

Tags: azul-zulu

In my Windows application I used to ship Oracle JRE 7 with two folder (x86) and (AMD64). Now I am replacing it with Zulu OpenJRE 7. But on Azul site I can only see (x86) package for download in zip and msi format.

Is AMD64 package for Zulu OpenJRE is not available? Or will (x86) package will work on AMD platform?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it's the same instruction set. Zulu works on "both" amd64 and x86-64.

Comment: Yes, Zulu JRE-64 bit works on both AMD64 and x86-64bit.  Actually I was unable to find package for Zulu JRE 7 64-bit. But now I got MSI packages for both 32bit and 64bit Zulu JRE7. Thanks Sergey.